# Signing a hash with EIP712

Tags: solidity, signature, ethers.js, hash, eip712

Is it possible to sign just a hash with the EIP712 standard (either within Solidity or Ethers.js)? If so, how?

All that I'm finding online is the full EIP712 process of `domain, types, values`, signing with Metamask or verifying the signature.

(The hash was properly generated following EIP712)

Thanks!